# Path to awk library

Tags: awk

I have an awk file `densel.awk` with the following call

```
@include "klnpan.awk"
```

There seems a need to include the path to "mylib.awk" even though it exists in the same directory because of

```
error: cannot open source file `klnpan.awk' for reading: No such file or directory
```

I aw running `densel.awk` as follows

```
awk -f "${path}"/densel.awk
```

Comment: What happens when you set `AWKPATH` to the directory your `klnpan.awk` is in?

Comment: When I checked it was empty.  Though it would have the path to the awk program as default.  I set it to the path of my awk files and the include file is getting picked up by the system properly.  In this the way to add include files by setting `AWKPATH` ?

Comment: Yes; `AWKPATH` tells `awk` where to find files.  The default is build dependent, but maybe something like `.:/usr/local/share/awk`

Comment: The customary way of defining libraries too ?  Did not know that.

Comment: `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` are two common OS variables.  But other applications may follow the same conventions; `AWKPATH` is specific to `awk` because that program was written to look for that variable.  Not all programs follow this concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` was written to look for variable `AWKPATH`.  This can contain a `:` separated string (similar to `$PATH`) where it will look for files.

The default value is build dependent, but maybe be something like `.:/usr/local/share/awk` which means it will look in the current directory and a system directory for files.

You can set this to your application directory;
e.g.

```
export AWKPATH=/path/to/awk/files
awk -f densel.awk
```

Comment: Which would also apply in calls such as `@include "klnpan.awk"`.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that, like [@include](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Include-Files), the [AWKPATH](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#AWKPATH-Variable) variable is a GNU awk extension, it's not part of [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) so don't expect either of those constructs to work with other awks.

Comment: ... another potentially interesting tidbit, gawk somewhat abuses the `ENVIRON` array by adding `AWKPATH` to it regardless of whether it's actually exported to the environment. It also appears to use the default value if the environment variable is set but empty. So you can poll the default value with `AWKPATH='' gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`.

Answer (score 1):

I do this in my .bashrc to set the AWKPATH:

```bash
    if [[ -d $HOME/gawk ]] && command -v gawk >/dev/null; then
        if [[ -n $AWKPATH ]]; then
            AWKPATH=$(gawk 'BEGIN {print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}')
            export AWKPATH
        fi
        if [[ ":$AWKPATH:" != *:"$HOME/gawk":* ]]; then
            AWKPATH+=":$HOME/gawk"
        fi
    fi
```

Substitute `$HOME/gawk` with the place you store your gawk libraries.

Also since all these features are exclusive to GNU awk, you might want to get used to typing `gawk`